# Change legend box names in Plotly (3D) Surface in R

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, legend, surface

I'm using the following code to create a 3D plot surface in R

```
superficie3d <- function(x.from,x.to,y.from,y.to,fxy,x.lab="x",y.lab="y",z.lab="z",main="",epsilon=0.01,sombra=FALSE,leyenda=TRUE){
  
  library(plotly)
  # from      := A partir de dónde corre esta coordenada.
  # to        := Hasta dónde corre esta coordenada.
  # fxy       := f(x,y) (función de R2 a R).
  # lab       := Nombre del eje/coordenada.
  # main      := Título del gráfico.
  # epsilon   := Precisión en la evaluación de la función.
  # sombra    := Se proyecta la sombra de la superficie.
  # leyenda   := Se muestra la leyenda.
  
  # Definimos dónde vamos a evaluar la superficie.
  x <- seq(x.from,x.to,epsilon)
  y <- seq(y.from,y.to,epsilon)
  z <- outer(X = x,Y = y,FUN = Vectorize(fxy)) %>% t()
  
  fig <- plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z,showscale=leyenda) %>% 
    add_surface(
      contours = list(
        z = list(
          show=sombra,
          usecolormap=TRUE,
          highlightcolor="#ff0000",
          project=list(z=TRUE)
        )
    )) %>% 
    layout(
      title = paste("\n",main),
      scene = list(
        xaxis = list(title = x.lab),
        yaxis = list(title = y.lab),
        zaxis = list(title = z.lab)
      ))
  
  return(fig)
  
  # Más información:
  # https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/#basic-3d-surface-plot
  # https://plotly.com/r/3d-axes/
  
}

fxy <- function(x,y){x^2 + y^2}
superficie3d(x.from = -3,x.to = 3,y.from = -5,y.to = 5,
             fxy = fxy,x.lab = "eje x",y.lab = "eje y", z.lab = "eje z",
             main = "Gráfico",sombra = TRUE)
```

And the result is

[image]

What I need is to change the labels in the box when you select a point in the plot. For example, instead of showing:

x: -0.33
y: -3.13
z: 9.9058

I'd like to see

eje x: -0.33
eje y: -3.13
eje z: 9.9058

Comment: This was asked a long time ago! Add the following to the function `add_surface`: `hovertemplate = paste0('eje x: %{x}<br>', 'eje y: %{y}<br>', 'eje z: %{z}<extra></extra>')` it should change the information in the tooltip to what you want.